# Asynchronous callback is my code correct and am I banned from the api?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Sorry to ask this question again. I have been on this same thing since the morning and can't seem to figure it out. the issue was that functions geo & weather are both asynchronous and I need geo to be completed before it moves onto weather.

I have made some advances and put a callback function in my geo function. It is returning to me "callback is not a function for some reason".

Although this was working before and I actually got an actual return for my weather. I might have gotten banned from ip-api for refreshing my page too much, but all I want to know is that if my code is correct and that it should run.

```js
$(function() {
    var lon;
    var lat;

    function geo(callback) {
        var url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            lon = 10;
            lat = 20;
            city = Toronto;
            $("#geo").html("Longitude " + lon + " Latitude " + lat + " City: " + city);
            console.log(lon, lat);
        });
callback();
    }


    function weather() {
        var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=2e261bce8053ef6131bb74b9d613dc6e"; //be very careful of the url
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $("#weather").html(data.main.temp);
        });

    }
    //
geo(weather);
    //
});
```

Comment: `It is returning to me "callback is not a function for some reason"` - where is this happening, the error should include a line number. I also guess `Toronto` is a global var defined somewhere else in the code, otherwise your code wouldn't run at all. and a second issue, you call `callback()` before the getJSON in geo is complete, that will mean lat and lon are not defined in the weather function

Comment: hey thanks for the reply! Where should i be doing the callback()? also the line for city = Toronto should = city = data.city. I was just testing something!

Comment: callback should be called about where you have the `console.log(lat, lon)`

Comment: okay cool! so lets say I have the callback(); under console.log. then the entire program should finish running my function "geo" then use that data to run my function "weather".

Comment: not quite, $.getJSON is asynchronous, so `geo` finishes before the `success` callback is called - that's why you need to execute `callback` inside the success callback

Comment: what do you mean by success callback? here is what I have so far

http://jsbin.com/wucuqe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thank you so muhc, i got it! i changed the API i was using for my geolocation.